# CSS table alternate colors

Tags: css

is there a version of css3 code below that will work in all browers?

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother too much about this. It works on all major browsers excluding IE (IE9 supports it though) and not having alternating colours isn't a big price to pay for using IE in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You have at least two options, though:

1. Manually apply a style to the odd (and/or) even rows and then style those appropriately: `tr.odd {background-color: #ccc; }`
2. Use JS (I'd suggest jQuery): `$('tr:nth-child(odd)').css('background-color','#ccc');` **or** `$('tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('odd')` (either of these would need to be in a `$(document).ready();` (or equivalent) though, obviously).

Comment: +1. I use jQuery to style mine. Something like `$('table.striped > tbody > tr:odd > td').addClass('odd');`

Comment: actually let me correct that, my php script is generating separate tables So how would I have to do something in the PHP code to tell it every other table set a background color?

Comment: You want a different background-color on alternating *tables*?

Comment: yes, sir. After testing out the code above I notice it was colorizing all rows. After looking at my code I noticed that its output a new table for every items. So I would have to alternating the table background color.

Comment: @acctman, I'd seriously suggest changing your php script to output **one** table containing **all** the rows; outputting a lot of one-row tables is (probably) semantically meaningless and structurally over-complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you modify the DOM (e.g. to add a class to every other row), either in the original markup or with JS after the content has loaded. (Even then it still won't support *all* browsers, as not all browsers support CSS, and not all that do have it turned on).